# MS Word Endnote Style Formatting

Tags: formatting

I hope this is the appropriate forum (and tags).

I have a book written in MS Word (2007) ... with probably 250 endnotes.  Every time I create an endnote, MS Word:

- automatically uses the internal "End Note Reference" style ...
- which first inserts a superscript number at the citation point in the text,
- then zips me down to the endnotes area where it inserts the same superscript end note number, and then allows me to enter in the citation text in whatever style I want (I use "footnote base")

Here's my problem:  The end note numbers don't quite format the way I want (in the end notes section).  I want the numbers to be normal-case (not superscript) and have and then indent before the citation text.

But MS Word makes the end note number the same style (ie... if I change the style to a non-superscript, then inside the text of the book, the end note numbers won't be "super" to the text.

I wish I could describe this better.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is this book going to be published and distributed? If it's going to be laid out by someone else, the superscripts and such won't matter. Your layout person can fix that.

Comment: Should this have the [tag:academic-writing] tag?

Comment: Yes, should have academic-writing tag. The requested format is the one preferred by the Chicago Manual of Style.

Comment: Based on the number of end notes, this is probably an academic work... but I asked because CMOS is *also* used for business writing, non-fiction books, even novels.

Comment: No. It's not an academic work (lots of assumptions up there). It's a business book - a very typical 65k word business book, and the number of notes are not that unusual for this kind of book.  Feel free to categorize this where-ever you want though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Word 2007 but you could try what works with 2010. Highlight the number in the end note. Right click it. Select 'Style' and then choose the style you want or modify the existing one. I chose a different style, but one that has the numbers as normal case and this didn't change the in-text reference size.

Edit: My wife, who is an academic and deals with this sort of thing often, said she just selects all the endnotes at one time and changes the font size so the numbers are are the same size as the text.

Comment: yes, this works - requiring me to change all 250 endnotes ... not really a solution.  Also - this doesn't really address the problem since MS word will create all new endnotes in the internal style.  The issue is that there are NOT two different styles used (internally) when MS word generates the superscript inside the text and the actual end note

Comment: Then do a find and replace style. This will replace every item of a particular style with another style.

Comment: Nope.   Since the style inside the Text (the superscript) is the SAME style as the endnote (at the end of the book) - I'd be replacing everything... I just want a different style for the endnote numbers

Comment: Can't you do 'Find next' and skip the style inside the text? Alternatively, just change the style in the endnotes using Ctrl - Y to repeat the change. 250 isn't that many. I've made bigger manual changes.